# Função JavaScript para pegar a próxima data de um calendário

Tags: javascript, data

Tenho vários calendários cadastrados na minha base dados, cada calendário tem sua particularidade.

Tenho uma tela que faz a inclusão de um arquivo e através de um `dropdown` eu escolho o calendário que a periodicidade desse arquivo vai respeitar.

Ex.: Diário, Semanal, Mensal e etc..

A ideia é quando o usuário clicar em um `textbox` específico aparece uma balãozinho avisando a próxima data disponível para o arquivo.

Ex.
Hoje é dia 28.

Balão: "A próxima data é dia 29/04/2015" se a periodicidade for diária.

Podem me ajudar a construir essa função com JavaScript?

Tentei utilizar o código abaixo, mas minha principal dúvida é como retorna a próxima data do calendário na função

```
function ExibeDica(obj, msg, useBottom, maxWidth){
       try
         {
        window.status = msg;
        var msgDica = document.getElementById('msgDica');               

        if(msgDica)
        {
            msgDicaTexto.innerHTML = msg;
            msgDica.style.zIndex = 9999;
            msgDica.style.left = obj.getClientRects()[0].left + document.body.scrollLeft - 2;
            msgDica.style.display = 'block';
            if (maxWidth != null)
                if (msgDica.offsetWidth > maxWidth) msgDica.style.width = maxWidth;
            if (useBottom)
                msgDica.style.top = obj.getClientRects()[0].bottom + document.body.scrollTop;
            else
                msgDica.style.top = obj.getClientRects()[0].top + document.body.scrollTop - msgDica.offsetHeight - 4;
        }
    }
    catch(e) {} 
}

function OcultaDica(){
    try
    {
        window.status = ''; 

        var msgDica = document.getElementById('msgDica');

        if(msgDica)
        {
            msgDica.style.display = 'none';
            msgDica.style.width = null;
        }
    } 
    catch(e) {}
}
```

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Eu tentei usar um código de uma dica que já tinha no projeto.. minha dúvida é realmente como trazer essa data pra função, vou colocar o código que tentei utilizar acima

Comment: Você já tem algum código feito (alguma tentativa) com relação ao problema (calcular a data)? O código colocado na pergunta não afeta em nada na solução do problema.

Answer (score 3):

Verifique os métodos dos objetos Date, com eles você pode, pegar a data atual, adicionar dias e/ou meses e usar a nova data.
Creio que no seu caso, baste pegar a data atual e acrescentar um dia, dá pra fazer isso assim:

```
// data atual (28)   
d = new Date();  

// acrescenta um dia (29)  
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

// exibe o "novo" dia (29)  
d.getDate();
```

Pode aplicar o mesmo às outras regras.